# How thymeleaf layout:decorator works

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have come across a piece of code in a springboot (1.3.2) - thymeleaf (2.1.4) - thymeleaf layout dialect (1.3.1) project I'm working where the content html file contains:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" layout:decorator="layout/sitelayout">
...

<div th:fragment="content" class="container">
....
</div>
```

And the sitelayout.html file contains:

```
<div layout:fragment="content">
    <h1>Static content for prototyping purposes only</h1>

    <p>
        This is the layout of the site. The actual content will come from individual views making use of this layout
    </p>
</div>
```

===================================================

I searched the web and could not find enough information / documentation example about how it works. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: really nice question! Why are there so few likes?!?

Answer (score 3):

**A Comprehensive Description:**

You know that the Thymeleaf is a **Template Engine** and uses several concepts:

- **Template:**
   Template is a concept and means that you can write your html files more generally (maybe including other templates). These template files
  finally will be processed by the Thymeleaf template engine in server side and creates a regular html file that will be send to the client.
- **Layout (a general concept):**
   Layout refers to the arrangement of text, images and other objects on a page, and it is the most
  interested matter of website designers. By the layout concept, you can
  specify overall structure/formatting of your pages. The layout files can be without content (only structure), or with some content that is shared by its callers.
- **Layout template (= Page Layout):**
   Layout template refers to a layout file with several fragments and empty tags, so that the layout callers (page
  templates) calls it and use its structure (while themselves have
  content also).
- **Page template:**
   Page template refers to html file of a page, so that can call other templates and fragments and use the layout
  template's structure. The page template finally will be converted to
  a regular html page by the Thymeleaf template engine.
- **Fragment:**
   Fragment is a part of a Template. Thymeleaf allows you to import fragments of a Template into another Template.

Usually, developers create several **layout templates** (for different page formats) that will be shared across other **page templates**.
The layout/page templates often contains some **fragments** such as page header, navigation, footer, and a main section where your main content will go.

**Now what is dialect?**
As you know, Thymeleaf is a tool allowing customization and for this purpose, Dialect allows you define how your Template will be processed.
In fact the `Layout dialect` performs decoration as per the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

**Different Dialects:**

1. The core library of Thymeleaf provides a dialect called **Standard

   Dialect**, which is enough for use for everyone and uses OGNL
   language to proccess a template.
2. Spring Framework creates a private dialect called **SpringStandard
   Dialect**. it is like the Thymeleaf standard dialect, but has minor
   adjustments for better use of some features in Spring Framework. For
   example:  It uses Spring Expression Language **(SpringEL) instead of
   using OGNL.** Therefore, if use Spring Framework, you should use this dialect.
3. **[thymeleaf-layout-dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect)** : which is a open source project and has
   more features that lets you build layouts and reusable templates in
   order to improve code reuse. This library uses `layout:` prefix for its attributes.
4. [Custom Dialect](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiT_I3P-droAhWOCWMBHQWVDzwQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thymeleaf.org%2Fdoc%2Ftutorials%2F3.0%2Fextendingthymeleaf.html&usg=AOvVaw0HiiMoPYPQ1_Y8rzzJdRrO): You can extends the Thymeleaf and create your
   own dialect.

**Example:** The thymeleaf in spring boot project with thymeleaf-layout-dialect(dialect number 3):

```
 <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 </dependency>
```

**Note: The reason of decorator OR decorate in dialect number (3):**
The Thymeleaf layout dialect **version 1.x** uses the `decorator` which was opposite to the `decorator pattern`.
So in the **version 2.x**, this mistake by introducing the `decorate` was solved.
Therefore although the **Thymeleaf and its layout dialect libraries** are backward-compatible, but it is better that use `layout:decorate` in your codes.

> While the layout dialect does perform decoration as per the decorator pattern, throughout 1.x it incorrectly identified the layout/parent template as the decorator, when instead, according to the design pattern, the extension (content template in this case) is the decorator. This change is simply a rename of the layout:decorator/data-layout-decorator processor to layout:decorate/data-layout-decorate so that the template being specified is the one being decorated, not the decorator, plus an overhaul of the documentation to fix this inconsistency.
>   
>   ref: https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/MigrationGuide.html
>   
>   So, you have to use the `layout:decorate` in your page templates and refer it to the main template.
>   The layout:decorate in the  tag says which layout template to decorate using this content template

**Example:**
https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/Examples.html#layouts

Answer (score 2):

I have information that should answer your question as how to work with this code. FYI, I do believe the code should say `layout:decorate` instead of `layout:decorator` in the HTML tag.

**Basic description of what Layout Dialect is**

> [...]Layout Dialect gives people the possibility of using hierarchical approach[...]. Thymeleaf Layout Dialect uses layout/decorator templates to style the content, as well as it can pass entire fragment elements to included pages. [...]

**References**

[Thymeleaf documentation on layout](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html)

- Go to number 4 to read specifically about `layout:decorate`.

[Baeldung tutorial on using Thymeleaf layout.](http://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-spring-layouts)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think finally I found a good tutorial about about thymeleaf layout template with the layout dialect here: https://medium.com/@trevormydata/week-5-thymeleaf-with-spring-mvc-rapid-introduction-to-the-essentials-799f1fba8c07

The layout:decorator processor was used in earlier version of thymeleaf ( https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/tree/master-thymeleaf-2.1 ). The latest version uses layout:decorate and therefore it was hard for me to get some documentation on layout:decorator.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually websites share common page components like the header, footer, menu and possibly many more. These page components can be used by the same or different layouts. There are two main styles of organizing layouts in projects: include style and hierarchical style. Both styles can be easily utilized with Thymeleaf without losing its biggest value: natural templating.

Source: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html